# Retrieving Mongo docs for a large fixed set of identifiers

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Mongo DB with about 200M+ documents. Each document has an "name" field (indexed) which is a string and an "items" field (not indexed) which is an array of integers. The size of the array can range from 1 to 100.

Say I have a txt file with about 1M names. I need to create another txt file containing "items" for each of those 1M names.

Options:

- Just iterate through the names one at a time and extract items based on _id.
- Create "batches" of small sets of names (say 100 at a time) and query the DB using the `$in` operator. Later iterate through the documents one by one.
- Use some sort of map-reduce to break up the 1M names and query them in parallel.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is very hard to answer without trying it and profiling.

Since the array is small and assuming that every name will be found then a brute-force scan of the database in its natural order may even be faster than any of the options you suggested.

Using parallel scan (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/parallelCollectionScan/) you can iterate over all the documents; you can easily hold the 1M names in memory and roughly once every 200 records you'll find a match to write to your output text file.

Comment: I didn't know about parallelCollectionScan, thanks for pointing me to it. Do you think that parallelCollectionScan will work better if the number of names is closer to the total document count ie., instead of 1M names, will 10M names work better than say 100K names?

Comment: As the number increases the percentage of records discarded goes down. At 200M the parallel scan would be as fast as you can get. At 1 record it's about the worst you could do. Precisely what shape the line is between those extremes and where it crosses the other solutions is hard to predict. I'm constantly surprised how well brute-force solutions do against 'cleverer' solutions: most disk and memory architecture is designed to handle the dumb, sequential process. You really need to benchmark using your chosen hardware.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I'll benchmark it carefully to see what's best. Another question - I see in the apidocs that parallelCollectionScan does not work with sharded clusters. Do you know why that is so?